# How do i get position instead of swapping in list number in python

Tags: python

I have numbers like this :

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 8, 6, 9, 1]
```

and I would like to put this number in a list like `[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9, 1]`

Comment: Is there a general case? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: I'm started learning and I trying to make this happened but I can't. So it's general case for me @olivier-melançon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `list.insert` and `list.pop`.

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 8, 6, 9, 1]

a.insert(0, a.pop(4))

# [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9, 1]
```

This deletes the item in position 4 and moves it to position 0. Remember that indexing in Python begins at 0.

Details on list methods available in Python [Data Structures documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment and clarification @jpp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove` (which removes the first instance of an element in your list) and `insert` (which inserts an element in any position you like):

```
a.remove(2)
a.insert(0, 2)   # 0 means insert at the first position in the list
```

However, if you're using `remove`, keep in mind that if the element you're trying to remove is not in your list, your code will raise a `ValueError`. Therefore, if you're not sure if an element is in your list, you should check before using `remove`:

```
if 2 in a:
    a.remove(2)
    a.insert(0,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use list indexing

```
> [a[4]]+a[:4]+a[4+1:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jpp [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470449/2808371) you could do the following, if you want to get dynamically the index value of number 2 in your list:

```
a.insert(0, a.pop(a.index(2)))
```

`a.index(2)` - will find the index of (first occurence of) number 2 in your list (which will return 4 in this case)

`a.pop(4)` - will remove 4th value from the list and return it(this returns 2)

`a.insert(0, 2)` - will insert value 2 into the list at index 0.